# Difference between the center set and the centroid set of a tree.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T$ be a tree, i.e. a connected graph without cycles.

A vertex $u$ is in the center set of $T$ if $\max\limits_{v} dist(u,v) \leq \max\limits_{v} dist(w,v)$ for any vertex $w$.

A vertex $u$ is in the centroid set of $T$ if the largest size of the components of $T - \{u\}$ is minimum.
In other words, let $T_1,\dots,T_k$ be the components of $T- \{u\}$, and $\tau(u) = \max \{|V(T_1)|, \dots, |V(T_k)|\}$.
The centroid set consists of vertices such that $\tau(u) = \min\limits_{v} \tau(v)$.

We can prove that both sets have size at most 2, one vertex or two adjacent vertices. Are the two definitions equivalent? Can we prove that these two sets are identical?

Answer (score 1):

However, they are essentially different. There are examples such that the distance between two sets is at least $k$ for any positive integer $k$.

Consider the star graph $K_{1,n}$, say $\{c,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ where $c$ is the center vertex and $x_i$ are the leaves.
Add a path of length $l$ with one end be the center of the star, say $c,y_1,\dots,y_l$.
For this graph, the center set $\{y_{\frac{l-1}2}\}$ or $\{y_{\frac l2 - 1}, y_{\frac l2}\}$, and the centroid set is $\{c\}$ if $l = o(n)$.

As $n$ approaches to infinity, let $l = \sqrt n$, the distance between the center set and the centroid set is about $\frac12 \sqrt n$, which is arbitrarily large.